# How to output a json object of Request.CreateResponse method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How to output a json object of Request.CreateResponse method?

the below code output the json string

```
    "{RowCount:15}"
```

,the string is not a json ojbect,it should use eval() method of javscript to convert to json object ,I want the server side return the json object directly,
It should return

```
{RowCount:15}
```

that's a json object.

**Code**

```
public class PagedDataAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        string jsonRowCount = "{RowCount:10}";
        actionExecutedContext.Response = actionExecutedContext.Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, jsonRowCount,System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.DefaultMediaType);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Instead of using a string, use an anonymous object:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
{
    var rowCount = new { RowCount = 10 };
    actionExecutedContext.Response = actionExecutedContext.Request.CreateResponse(
        HttpStatusCode.OK,
        rowCount,
        JsonMediaTypeFormatter.DefaultMediaType
    );
}
```

Comment: Holy Moly.  For future readers and searchers, I was (errantly) doing this:  JObject jo = /* Some Code that created JObject */
string outputJsonContent = jo.ToString(Formatting.None);
HttpResponseMessage resp = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, outputJsonContent, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
I should have been doing this : (as this answer says)  JObject jo = /* Some Code that created JObject */
HttpResponseMessage resp = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, jo, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());    /* FYI #region Assembly Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0 : Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject */